# Remove random numbers in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

sorry to ask, it's probably easy question but my timing is really tight to understand how to solve this myself.

I'm working on cleaning a SMS file for evidence to police.
I have to remove stuff like this

sc_ service_center="95000658"    date_sent="1644955111000"

Numbers are randoms, I have to remove this by hand for now, more than 6000 sms

If one can explain, or just type in the solution for me. That'd be saving a lot of people time.

Thanks to anyone helping!

Answer (score 0):

Simple with regular expressions. Use the Replace dialog with:

Find what: `service_center="\d+" date_sent="\d+"`
Replace with: `service_center="xxxxxx" date_sent="yyyyyy"`

The `d+` stands for one or more digits.

Here is an example after doing Replace All:

[image]

Comment: AAaah, I did used "\d+" but as Extended mode !
Excellent, thank you my man ! You're saving a lot of people day !

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).